# Почему функция возвращает None?

Tags: python, python-3.x

В моем коде имеется следующая функция, которая возвращает `None`.

```
def sumbeforeREC(a, Sum=0):
    if a == 1:
        return Sum
    Sum += a - 1
    print(Sum)
    a -= 1
    sumbeforeREC(a, Sum)
print(sumbeforeREC(5))
```

Какие есть объяснения такого поведения данной функции?

Comment: `return sumbeforeREC(a, Sum)`

Comment: В Python функция которая ничего не возвращает через `return` фактически возвращает `None`.